# How to automatically re-run a process (python code) that keeps crashing using bash or terminal?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, twitter

I have a Python code that keeps crashing while retrieving information from Twitter due to API limitations. How can I run the process again automatically every time it crashes?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 578, in _readinto_chunked
    n = self._safe_readinto(mvb)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 625, in _safe_readinto
    raise IncompleteRead(bytes(mvb[0:total_bytes]), len(b))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 2880 more expected)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 331, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 413, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 448, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 478, in readinto
    return self._readinto_chunked(b)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 589, in _readinto_chunked
    raise IncompleteRead(bytes(b[0:total_bytes]))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(5530 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mona_counthash_stream.py", line 248, in <module>
    streamer.filter(languages=["en"], track=unique_hashtags[:367])
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 450, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 364, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 297, in _run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 266, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 325, in _read_loop
    next_status_obj = buf.read_len(length)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 164, in read_len
    self._buffer += self._stream.read(read_len)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 430, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 349, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(5530 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(5530 bytes read))
```

and this happens despite I am using `pass` in my code:

```
from urllib3.exceptions import ProtocolError
import http

except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print("Tweepy Error is: ", e.reason)
    pass
except http.client.IncompleteRead as e:
    print("http exception is: ", e)
    pass
except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
    print("Unicode error is: ", e)
    pass

#except urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError as e:
except ProtocolError as e:
    print("url exception is:", e)
    time.sleep(15*60)
    pass
except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    pass
```

Comment: `yes | while read line; do python ... ; done`

Comment: Or better yet loop what you want from within script itself. When exception occurred, maybe call script itself again via `os.exec()` function